# AWS MongoDB [ReplicationExecutor] Error in heartbeat request to xxx ExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sharding, replicaset

I have replica set (hosted on amazon) which has:

- primary
- secondary
- arbiter

All of them are version 3.2.9 and this replica is making one shard in my sharded cluster (if that is important although I think it is not).

When I type `rs.status()` on primary it says that cannot reach secondary, secondary cannot reach arbiter and arbiter cannot reach primary:

On Primary:
`{
    "set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-06-16T18:43:23.992Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(-1),
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "name" : "secondaryIP:27017",
            "health" : 0,
            "state" : 8,
            "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
            "uptime" : 0,
            "optime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2017-06-16T18:43:22.767Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2017-06-16T18:43:22.931Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Couldn't get a connection within the time limit",
            "configVersion" : -1
        },`

On Secondary: 
`{"set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-06-16T19:08:23.364Z"),
    "myState" : 2,
    "term" : NumberLong(-1),
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "ip-x-x-x-x:27017",
            "health" : 0,
            "state" : 8,
            "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
            "uptime" : 0,
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2017-06-16T19:08:21.404Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2017-06-16T19:08:21.424Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Couldn't get a connection within the time limit",
            "configVersion" : -1
        }`

On Arbiter: 
`{"set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-06-16T17:54:22.552Z"),
    "myState" : 7,
    "term" : NumberLong(-1),
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "name" : "primaryIP:27017",
            "health" : 0,
            "state" : 8,
            "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
            "uptime" : 0,
            "optime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2017-06-16T17:54:13.027Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2017-06-16T17:54:22.107Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Couldn't get a connection within the time limit",
            "configVersion" : -1
        }`

From the error log on primary:
`2017-06-16T18:40:25.030+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from appIP:60768 #256386 (23 connections now open)
2017-06-16T18:40:28.762+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to connect to secondaryIP:27017 - ExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out
2017-06-16T18:40:28.762+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Error in heartbeat request to secondaryIP:27017; ExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out
2017-06-16T18:40:28.762+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to secondaryIP:27017
2017-06-16T18:40:34.761+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Error in heartbeat request to secondaryIP:27017; ExceededTimeLimit: Couldn't get a connection within the time limit
2017-06-16T18:40:46.761+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Error in heartbeat request to secondaryIP:27017; ExceededTimeLimit: Couldn't get a connection within the time limit
2017-06-16T18:40:48.762+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to connect to secondaryIP:27017 - ExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out
2017-06-16T18:40:48.762+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Error in heartbeat request to secondaryIP:27017; ExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out
2017-06-16T18:40:48.762+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to secondaryIP:27017`

I am unable to connect to any of the IPs with `mongo --host <IP>` and I get timed out.

All the replica sets are in the same EC2 security group.

This is very similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485285/mongodb-replica-heartbeat-request-time-exceeded) but I couldn't understand the answer given on that issue.

I can provide more info if needed.

The database is still reachable and responsive in the app but there are some inconsistencies with numbers and logs which are likely to be due to this connection errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, AWS security group didn't have the IPs of the replica sets in the `Custom TCP Rule` defined.
Adding those rules got the replica sets back into connected status.